# altbeacon-IOS, Only the ibeacon is not being scanned

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, beacon, altbeacon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVm58.png)

I used swiftUI, and it was confirmed that the header bridge was also working properly.
As you can see in the image, the altbeacon is scanning fine,
but not the ibeacon.

I set the layout like this
setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25")

, is there any problem? please check.

I tried changing the layout like this, but it didn't work.
setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has set up beacon scanning on iOS using the [AltBeacon iOS Beacon Tools](https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools)

The above tools help iOS scan and decode Eddystone, AltBeacon and other BLE beacon formats using iOS CoreBluetooth APIs under the hood.

However, the above tools **cannot detect iBeacon** because iOS blocks the underlying CoreBluetooth APIs from getting scan results for iBeacon advertisements.  In order to detect iBeacon you must use CoreLocation APIs alongside what you are already doing.  While this is duplicative, unfortunately Apple requires this duplication by sandboxing iBeacon from other BLE advertisements.

Comment: thank you. I have been waiting so long for your reply! Have a good day!